# Create a collection with userId or filter collection based on userId

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

New to NoSQL (coming from the relational db world) and looking for best practice advice.

When using firestore, am I better off (faster/reduce # of reads) filtering a collection based on say userId, or should I create a root collection with the userId and create subcollections for the different data for that particular user?

Eg.

(1) should I insert all users data into a 'subscriptions (col) -> (doc) -> (fields, including userId). In my read, I am using a where clause to filter out data in the collection based on the userId

.Collection("subscriptions")

.WhereEqualsTo("Author", _auth.GetCurrentUserId())

[image]

or (2) should I create the root collection as the userId (Author in the above case) and then insert the different collections of data for that user and nest collections there?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also posted on: https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/n97tlh/create_a_collection_with_userid_or_filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firestore the number of documents in a collection has no impact on the performance of reading from that collection. That's one of its main, unique guarantees. So for read performance (or cost) there is no difference between storing all user data in a single collection, or creating a collection per user.

Where this does make a difference is in write performance, which is typically a "bigger" concern when using Firestore and scaling your app. Write throughput is mainly limited when updates are writing to the same index(es), which is much more likely when you are storing the user data in a single, top-level collection. So for that reason I usually store user-specific data in user-specific subcollections.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the second paragraph please, are you saying I am better off using the root collection as my userID and then storing that user's data as collections/docs? From my question, it would be (2). So in this case, my root collection would be a collection of userId's and the subcollections would be documents pertaining to that user alone.

Comment: Read performance is not the reason for choosing one or the other. I would recommend considering write performance/limitations a bigger factor - in which case having per-user subcollection makes most sense.